# how and where can i place my header() so that my if else condition can run a number of times?

Tags: php, header, echo, alert

I have a system for users to apply for permit...when they select their permits they wish to retire, my system should be able to check if the meet the criteria or if they have applied for that permit before to prevent spam.

However, I have a big problem. If I put `header('Location:s_success.php');` the alert wouldn't appear. For example, because user can choose 1 or 2 or more permits, .

**Scenario**

Let's say the choose one permit which they are eligible to apply for and another permit which they are not eligible yet.

**Expected Result**

In this case, what should happen is that system should brink them to the success page and at the same time alert them that the other permit which they are not eligible for is not successful.

**But Unexpected Result:**

They system just go to success page without warning the user that the not eligible permit is not successful.

This is my **code**:

```
<?php
session_start();
include'Connections/database.php';
$conn = dbConnect ();
    if (! $conn)
    die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
    
    $user = $_SESSION['eid'];
    $selectedPermit=$_POST['cat'];
    $_SESSION['selectedPermit']=$selectedPermit;
    
    foreach($selectedPermit as $permit)
    {
        $query="SELECT t.PREREQ1, t.PREREQ2, (CASE WHEN (t.PREREQ1 IS NOT NULL) AND (p1.PTYPE IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS missing1, (CASE WHEN (t.PREREQ2 IS NOT NULL) AND (p2.PTYPE IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS missing2 FROM type AS t LEFT JOIN permit AS p1 ON (t.PREREQ1=p1.ptype) AND ( p1.EID = '$user' ) AND (p1.STATUS='approved') LEFT JOIN permit AS p2 ON (t.PREREQ2=p2.ptype) AND ( p2.EID = '$user' ) AND (p2.STATUS='approved') WHERE t.PTYPE = '$permit' ";
        $result=mysql_query($query,$conn);
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $missing1=$row['missing1'];
        $missing2=$row['missing2'];
        
        if($missing1=='1' or $missing2=='1')
        {
            $message='You have not met the pre-requisites for '. $permit .' \n';
//              echo "You did have not met the Pre-Requisites for." .$permit;
            echo "<script>alert(\"$message\");";
//              header('Location:s_apply2.php');
            echo "location.href='s_apply2.php';</script>";
        }
        elseif($missing1 =='0' and $missing2 =='0')
        {
            $query="SELECT PTYPE FROM permit WHERE EID='$user'";
            $result=mysql_query($query);
            
            if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
            {
                $query="SELECT MED FROM emp WHERE EID='$user'";
                    $result=mysql_query($query);
                    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $med=$row['MED'];
                
                    if($med == 'yes')
                    {
//                          echo "You are Fine.";
                        $query = "INSERT INTO permit (EID, PTYPE) VALUES ('$user','$permit' )";
                        mysql_query($query);
                        header('Location:s_apply_success.php');
                    }
                    else
                    {
//                          echo "Go do Medical form";
                        header('Location:medical_question.php');
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $appliedPermit[]=$row['PTYPE'];
                }
            
                if(in_array($permit,$appliedPermit))
                {
                        $message1='You have already applied '. $permit .' before. \n';
//                          echo"You have already applied for ".$permit ." before <br/>";
                        echo "<script>alert(\"$message1\");";
//                          header('Location:s_apply2.php');
                        echo "location.href='s_apply2.php';</script>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $query="SELECT MED FROM emp WHERE EID='$user'";
                    $result=mysql_query($query);
                    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $med=$row['MED'];
                
                    if($med == 'yes')
                    {
                    //  echo "You are Fine.";
                        $query = "INSERT INTO permit (EID, PTYPE) VALUES ('$user','$permit' )";
                        mysql_query($query);
                        header('Location:s_apply_success.php');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Go do Medical form";
                    //  header('Location:medical_question.php');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    dbDisconnect($conn);
  
?>
```

**Suspected error:**

In my code, I suspect that because I am using `header('Location:s_apply_success.php');` therefore causes the unexpected result to happen. But I cannot confirm if this is the mistake.

**What I have tried to do to debug the suspected error**:

But I did try to use `echo "You are Fine.";` instead of `header('Location:s_apply_success.php');` and it works. It did shoe the echo and the pop up.

Comment: @Chibuzo no error but the alert just did not appear, it just go to the header.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
>
> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Comment: hmm...does it say that i cannot put `header()` before the loop end?? after reading it, i am not sure if i interpret correctly...thanks

Comment: but if i cant put header before the end, where should i put it?? thanks for guidance#

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up, you cannot display or show anything before header(), pass a message to the next page.

Comment: Nope I can go to header but the alert cannot appear

Answer (score 0):

[Output buffering](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) will compensate for your echoing of output before calling `header()`:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
include'Connections/database.php';
$conn = dbConnect ();
    if (! $conn)
    die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");

    $user = $_SESSION['eid'];
    $selectedPermit=$_POST['cat'];
    $_SESSION['selectedPermit']=$selectedPermit;

    foreach($selectedPermit as $permit)
    {
        $query="SELECT t.PREREQ1, t.PREREQ2, (CASE WHEN (t.PREREQ1 IS NOT NULL) AND (p1.PTYPE IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS missing1, (CASE WHEN (t.PREREQ2 IS NOT NULL) AND (p2.PTYPE IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS missing2 FROM type AS t LEFT JOIN permit AS p1 ON (t.PREREQ1=p1.ptype) AND ( p1.EID = '$user' ) AND (p1.STATUS='approved') LEFT JOIN permit AS p2 ON (t.PREREQ2=p2.ptype) AND ( p2.EID = '$user' ) AND (p2.STATUS='approved') WHERE t.PTYPE = '$permit' ";
        $result=mysql_query($query,$conn);
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $missing1=$row['missing1'];
        $missing2=$row['missing2'];

        if($missing1=='1' or $missing2=='1')
        {
            $message='You have not met the pre-requisites for '. $permit .' \n';
//              echo "You did have not met the Pre-Requisites for." .$permit;
            echo "<script>alert(\"$message\");";
//              header('Location:s_apply2.php');
            echo "location.href='s_apply2.php';</script>";
        }
        elseif($missing1 =='0' and $missing2 =='0')
        {
            $query="SELECT PTYPE FROM permit WHERE EID='$user'";
            $result=mysql_query($query);

            if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
            {
                $query="SELECT MED FROM emp WHERE EID='$user'";
                    $result=mysql_query($query);
                    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $med=$row['MED'];

                    if($med == 'yes')
                    {
//                          echo "You are Fine.";
                        $query = "INSERT INTO permit (EID, PTYPE) VALUES ('$user','$permit' )";
                        mysql_query($query);
                        header('Location:s_apply_success.php');
                    }
                    else
                    {
//                          echo "Go do Medical form";
                        header('Location:medical_question.php');
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $appliedPermit[]=$row['PTYPE'];
                }

                if(in_array($permit,$appliedPermit))
                {
                        $message1='You have already applied '. $permit .' before. \n';
//                          echo"You have already applied for ".$permit ." before <br/>";
                        echo "<script>alert(\"$message1\");";
//                          header('Location:s_apply2.php');
                        echo "location.href='s_apply2.php';</script>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $query="SELECT MED FROM emp WHERE EID='$user'";
                    $result=mysql_query($query);
                    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $med=$row['MED'];

                    if($med == 'yes')
                    {
                    //  echo "You are Fine.";
                        $query = "INSERT INTO permit (EID, PTYPE) VALUES ('$user','$permit' )";
                        mysql_query($query);
                        header('Location:s_apply_success.php');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Go do Medical form";
                    //  header('Location:medical_question.php');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dbDisconnect($conn);
    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: is there other methods? i never seen ouput buffing before...new thing to learn thou